# SUM aggregate function issue

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a `SUM` aggregate function in the outer query and inner query, this i need to minimize to one `SUM` function either in outer query or inner query. I should `group by item, loc, dur, startdate` because I will get duplicate values.

I tried using the `WITH` clause, but it didn't work. Someone told me that I can fix this using the `row_Number` analytical function, but don't know how to use it here.

```
L_Week_Start_Date = TO_DATE('02/DEC/2018', 'DD/MOM/YYYY')
SELECT Item,
       Loc,
       Dur,
       StartDate,
       SUM(P1) P1,
       SUM(P8) P8,
       SUM(P15) P15,
       SUM(P22) P22
FROM
  (SELECT DISTINCT SkuXFcst.Item Item,
                   SkuXFcst.Loc Loc,
                   '10080' Dur,
                           L_Week_Start_Date StartDate,
                           (CASE
                                WHEN SkuXFcst.StartDate BETWEEN L_Week_Start_Date 
                                                            AND L_Week_Start_Date + 6 
                                      THEN SUM(SkuXFcst.Qty) OVER(PARTITION BY SkuXFcst.Item, SkuXFcst.Loc)
                                ELSE 0
                            END) P1,
                           (CASE
                                WHEN SkuXFcst.StartDate BETWEEN L_Week_Start_Date + 7 
                                                            AND L_Week_Start_Date + 13 
                                       THEN SUM(SkuXFcst.Qty) OVER(PARTITION BY SkuXFcst.Item, SkuXFcst.Loc)
                                ELSE 0
                            END) P8,
                           (CASE
                                WHEN SkuXFcst.StartDate BETWEEN L_Week_Start_Date + 14 
                                                           AND L_Week_Start_Date + 20 
                                        THEN SUM(SkuXFcst.Qty) OVER(PARTITION BY SkuXFcst.Item, SkuXFcst.Loc)
                                ELSE 0
                            END) P15,
                           (CASE
                                WHEN SkuXFcst.StartDate BETWEEN L_Week_Start_Date + 21 
                                                            AND L_Week_Start_Date + 27 
                                       THEN SUM(SkuXFcst.Qty) OVER(PARTITION BY SkuXFcst.Item, SkuXFcst.Loc)
                                ELSE 0
                            END) P22
   FROM SCPOMGR.SkuExternalFcst SkuXFcst,
        SCPOMGR.Sku Sku
   WHERE SkuXFcst.Item = Sku.Item
     AND SkuXFcst.Loc = Sku.Loc
     AND ((SkuXFcst.StartDate BETWEEN Sku.U_Range_Start AND Sku.U_Range_End)
          OR Sku.U_Range_Start = TO_DATE('01/01/1970', 'DD/MM/YYYY')))
GROUP BY Item,
         Loc,
         Dur,
         StartDate
```

Comment: Please add sample data and expected output

Comment: Sample Data
============
Item  Loc Startdate  Dur  Qty
-----------------------------
21257 903 11-Dec-18 14400 100
21257 664 10-Dec-18 14400 100
11064 101 26-NOV-18 43200 300
21257 315 01-DEC-18 14400 100
21257 314 10-DEC-18 14400 100
21257 903 10-DEC-18 14400 1000
19510 502 20-DEC-18 14400 50
19510 502 20-DEC-18 14400 500
19507 615 20-DEC-18 14400 50
19507 615 22-DEC-18 14400 50

Comment: Output
===============
Item  Loc Startdate  P1  P8   P15  P22
----------------------------------
19510 502 01-DEC-18  0   0    1100  0
21257 314 01-DEC-18  0   100  0     0
21257 664 01-DEC-18  0   100  0     0
21257 903 01-DEC-18  0   100  0     0
11064 101 01-DEC-18  0   0    0     0
21257 315 01-DEC-18  100 0    0     0
19507 615 01-DEC-18  0   0    100   100

Comment: Add your data to the question by editing it and not as comments. Comments are not suitable for this.

Comment: SCPOMGR - is it jda? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
create table SkuXFcst as
SELECT 21257 as item, 903 as loc, TO_DATE('2018-12-11')as startdate, 14400 as dur , 100 as qty from dual union all
SELECT 21257, 664, TO_DATE('2018-12-10'), 14400, 100 from dual union all
SELECT 11064, 101, TO_DATE('2018-11-26'), 43200, 300 from dual union all
SELECT 21257, 315, TO_DATE('2018-12-01'), 14400, 100 from dual union all
SELECT 21257, 314, TO_DATE('2018-12-10'), 14400, 100 from dual union all
SELECT 21257, 903, TO_DATE('2018-12-10'), 14400, 1000 from dual union all
SELECT 19510, 502, TO_DATE('2018-12-20'), 14400, 50  from dual union all
SELECT 19510, 502, TO_DATE('2018-12-20'), 14400, 500 from dual union all
SELECT 19507, 615, TO_DATE('2018-12-20'), 14400, 50  from dual union all
SELECT 19507, 615, TO_DATE('2018-12-22'), 14400, 50  from dual union all
SELECT 19510, 502, TO_DATE('2018-12-01'), 0    , 0   from dual ;



SELECT  item,
        loc,
        dur,
        SUM(CASE
              WHEN SkuXFcst.StartDate BETWEEN  to_date('2018-12-02','YYYY-MM-DD')    
                                      AND      to_date('2018-12-02','YYYY-MM-DD')+ 6 THEN SkuXFcst.Qty
              ELSE 0
            END) AS P1,
        SUM(CASE
              WHEN SkuXFcst.StartDate BETWEEN  to_date('2018-12-02','YYYY-MM-DD') + 7 
                                      AND      to_date('2018-12-02','YYYY-MM-DD') + 13 THEN SkuXFcst.Qty
              ELSE 0
            END) P8,
        SUM(CASE
              WHEN SkuXFcst.StartDate BETWEEN  to_date('2018-12-02','YYYY-MM-DD') + 14 
                                      AND      to_date('2018-12-02','YYYY-MM-DD') + 20 THEN SkuXFcst.Qty
              ELSE 0
            END) P15,
        SUM(CASE
              WHEN SkuXFcst.StartDate BETWEEN  to_date('2018-12-02','YYYY-MM-DD') + 21 
                                      AND      to_date('2018-12-02','YYYY-MM-DD') + 27 THEN SkuXFcst.Qty
              ELSE 0
            END) P22
from    SkuXFcst
GROUP   BY item,
           loc,
           dur
```